# Do you call in sick, or call out sick?

Tags: word-choice

What would be the proper way to phrase the sentence?

When an employee has the flu, they should call in sick.

When an employee has the flu, they should call out sick.

Comment: This [n-gram is interesting](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=call+in+sick+%2B+called+in+sick%2Ccall+out+sick+%2B+called+out+sick&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28call%20in%20sick%20%2B%20called%20in%20sick%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28call%20out%20sick%20%2B%20called%20out%20sick%29%3B%2Cc0)  Not only does it show which is clearly preferred, but that the whole concept didn't begin until the 1950s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Call in sick** because it means to telephone somewhere, especially the place you work, to tell them what you are doing, where you are, etc. but it is not the definition of **call out**.